# How does little-endian processor save a number in their memory in C?

Tags: c, endianness

```
short a = 0x1234;
char *p = &a;
printf("%x%x", *p, *(p+1));

output
3412
```

I'm curious about how memory store a value 0x1234. I firstly thought 0x1234 is saved as 0x3412(reversed per byte) in memory, but according to lsb 0 numbering, it seems right that memory saves 0x1234 as 0x2c48(reversed per bit) I think that the value 0x1234 is saved in memory as 0x2c48 and little-endian cpu regards 0x2c48 as 0x1234. Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe it is saved as 0x2c (or maybe it isn't) but when you read it back from memory, don't you think the CPU would reverse it back to 0x34?

Comment: @user253751 According to wikipedia's quotation 'Little-endian CPUs usually employ "LSB 0" bit numbering', I think two situation. First one is memory store a value as LSbyte and CPU numbering as LSbit or second one is memory store a value as LSbit and CPU read a memory directly. It's viewpoint that programming language only can access per byte but actually there exists a bit order in a byte.

Comment: There is no such thing as "accessing directly".

Comment: @user253751 My writing won't be all exact because I've been learning C without any knowledge about computer. I wanted to deliver you my thought in the case of little-endian CPU, according to the wikipedia, it use a bit numbering not a byte numbering.

Comment: And why does it matter which way the bits are numbered? With `*p` you are fetching 8 bits at once. You are not fetching bit 0, bit 1, bit 2, bit 3, ..., bit 7. If the CPU reverses bits, then it's going to un-reverse them when you fetch 8 at once.

Comment: @user253751 I am purely curious what happening in computer when I save some multi byte value. That code means only program showed me 0x1234 as 0x34, 0x12 on my computer system. And followed lines are what I really want to know.

Comment: @user253751 There _is_ such a thing as "accessing directly", when you work with systems that dump memory contents directly into files in the way it's stored in memory. Seen plenty of file formats like that. But yea, that doesn't affect bits.

Comment: @Nyerguds No there is not. The processor would still apply bit-endianness.

Comment: @user253751 I did mention that, yes. Doesn't affect bits.

Comment: @Nyerguds It's not "direct" in the way that lev.1 code wants.

Comment: @user253751 True.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a little-endian system a multi-byte word is stored in reverse *byte* order.

So e.g. the 16-bit word `0x1234` will be stored with `0x34` in the low address, and `0x12` in the high address.

As a byte array it would be

```
uint8_t word[2] = { 0x34, 0x12 };
```

Bits of a byte are never reversed.

---

A 32-bit (four byte) word like `0x12345678` would be stored in the order `0x78`, `0x56`, `0x34` and `0x12` (low to high address).

Comment: Then `0x12345678` is stored in the order `0x78`, `0x56`, `0x34`, `0x12`. For binary bit order, it's `0111 1000` `0101 0110` `0011 0100` `0001 0010`, and each bit's number by lsb 0 numbering is '87654321', '161514131211109', '2423222120191817', '3231302928272625'. This sequence right?

Comment: @lev.1code You can't address single bits, their order is fixed. `0x78` is `0111 1000` as you say, but it's still `0x78` no matter the ***byte*** order. Endianness only deals with ***byte*** ordering. On a big-endian system `0x78` is *also* `0111 1000`, and it doesn't reverse like `0x87`.

Comment: There is also [middle-endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian) that mixes high-low sequences on byte and word level. At the end of the day you need to know exactly how your system works, if you are fiddling with multi-byte values and their separated bytes.

Comment: Bits of a word *could* be reversed, but you'll never know because the CPU un-reverses them when you read them. There's no way to tell, because of the fact that bits don't have addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Little Endian processors store the least significant Byte first and then more significant bytes.

e.g. `short int a = 0x1234` will be stored as

```
|------|------|
| 0x34 | 0x12 |
|------|------|
```

A 32 bit integer `unsigned int b = 0x12345678` is stored as

```
|------|------|------|------|
| 0x78 | 0x56 | 0x34 | 0x12 |
|------|------|------|------|
```

Answer (score 1):

*It is impossible to find out* which "order" your CPU stores bits in, because you cannot address individual bits.

Little-endian means the CPU stores the lowest byte first. But what does *first* mean? It means with the lowest address. Bits don't have addresses, so there's no way to tell which one is first. End of story.

Here's how we tell whether a CPU is little-endian with bytes:

```
         LITTLE ENDIAN                 BIG ENDIAN

words:      0x1234           words:      0x1234       
        /---------------\            /---------------\

bytes:    0x34     0x12      bytes:    0x34     0x12  
        /------\ /------\            /------\ /------\

        +------+ +------+            +------+ +------+
        | 0x34 | | 0x12 |            | 0x34 | | 0x12 |
        +------+ +------+            +------+ +------+

Address:  5000     5001      Address:  5001     5000
```

I have written the bytes in the same order on both sides, but the address is different.

That's how you tell the difference between little-endian and big-endian. You write a word to address 5000, then you check whether the byte with address 5000 contains 0x34 or 0x12.

Now, with bits you have this situation:

```
        LITTLE BIT-ENDIAN             BIG BIT-ENDIAN

bytes:        0x34           words:        0x34       
        /---------------\            /---------------\

        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+                                                          
bits:   |0|0|1|0|1|1|0|0|    bits:   |0|0|1|0|1|1|0|0|
        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

address:      5000                          5000
```

I have written the bits in the same order on both sides, but the address is the same. Only the byte has an address. The individual bits don't have addresses. If they had addresses, you could ask for, say, bit 5000.4 and see whether it's 1 or a 0 to figure out whether bits are little-endian or big-endian, but they don't, so you can't.

If you store a byte and then read it back, you will get the same byte value, no matter whether your system has little-endian or big-endian bits.